# Why is my my list of dataframes not concatenating as it should be?

Tags: python, powerbi

I am trying to get snapshots of my data by taking a given dataframe and saving it in a list. I am doing this in power bi data transformation adding a python script. Every time the list meets a certain time criteria lets say a given hour. It should add this data frame into a list where it gets concatenated together into one dataframe. I dont know if this can be done in power bi. I once did it years ago but don't remember how I did it.

This is the my code in power bi data transformation:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import pytz

east_time = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
date_time_east = datetime.now(east_time)
date_time_east_hour = date_time_east.strftime("%H")
date_time_east_minute = date_time_east.strftime("%H:%M")

update_time = "12"
frames = []
final = pd.DataFrame(data = dataset)
today = date.today()
final['Date'] = date_time_east_minute

if date_time_east_hour == update_time:
    frames.append(final)
else:
    pass

combined = pd.concat(frames)
```

This is my result:

[power bi dataset(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqsrx.png)

The issue is when I do this. It seems not to save the previous dataframes that I thought were added to the list and only puts out the most recent dataframe. I'd like it to save the previous dataframes to the list then concatenate them so it has previous timestamped values.

Comment: Could you make a small reproducible data example for `dataset`

Comment: It seems to me that the script is called several times, so values ​​may disappear. Maybe you must save dataframes to file? And then get dataframes from this file.

Comment: I added my results which are just snapshots of the original dataset. Essentially the same thing just has the date column added. How would I save dataframes to file?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but a quick [documentation read gives](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

> Append rows of other to the end of caller, returning a new object.

So this shuld do it:

```
frames = frames.append(final)
```

Comment: This does not work. I get a ADO.NET: Python script error.
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable